# Windows Service Never Restarted from C# Code

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have written a code to restart my windows service but it never works properly. Service is able to stop but never start again. My Project is self hosted WCF service inside a Windows Service. below is the code.

**Restart Method**

```
    public static void RestartService(string serviceName)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceController svc = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            if (svc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) svc.Stop();
            svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));
            svc.Start();
            svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));
            svc.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.WriteException(ex);
        }
    }
```

**Main Program**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun =
            { 
                new MyService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: To be clear - is that restart code running in another application or running within the service itself? Secondly, `catch(Exception)` with no code within it is going to be less than helpful in helping you track down errors - if you don't know what errors are going to happen or have any strategy for dealing with them, let them escape rather than catching them - at least that way you should have some information in the event log rather than (as here) absolute silence because you're hiding errors.

Comment: The code is inside the static class but within the same project.

Comment: From event viewer what i see the error is "Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller"

Comment: "I'm sawing off the branch of this tree that I'm sitting on. Why won't I stay afloat in the air?"

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to manage restart of services is by using Windows Service Recovery Actions, described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx).

They allow you to tell the Service Control Manager what to do in the event of a failure, including any restart actions, how many times to attempt a restart, and how long to wait between attempts.

This is way more robust than anything you could write in the service code itself.